# Xamarin Forms iOS C# catch exception not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin Forms app running on iOS that uses the iOS LocationManager to get the users location.
There are random times where this is not working but instead of the code hitting my try / catch exception block, it throws SIGABRT System.InvalidOperationException.

I think I am hitting a problem listed in the following article about iOS Exception Marshaling but I don't fully understand the article and didn't see a solution in the article other than using Build-Time Flags but even that is confusion in that I don't know which flags I am suppose to use.
I think I need to convert the iOS Objective-C exception into a C# exception with the flags but not sure which flag to use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/exception-marshaling

Here is the code block that I use in iOS and would like to know how to catch the exception and return "null" when there is an error rather than crash the app.

```cs
try
{
    using (cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => taskCompletionSource.SetCanceled(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
    {
        // request the current location
        locationManager.RequestLocation();

        // return the task to the caller
        return await taskCompletionSource.Task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // LOG THE EXCEPTION

    // return null so we don't blow up the calling code for now.
    return null;
}
finally
{
    // remove the attached handler
    locationManager.LocationsUpdated -= handler;

    locationManager.Dispose();
}
```

Here is the stack trace it sends me.

> TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult].SetCanceled ()
> LocationService+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__1 ()
> <.cctor>b__26_0 (System.Object obj)
> CancellationCallbackInfo.ExecutionContextCallback (System.Object obj)
> ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback,
> System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback,
> System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback,
> System.Object state) CancellationCallbackInfo.ExecuteCallback ()
> CancellationTokenSource.CancellationCallbackCoreWork
> (System.Threading.CancellationCallbackCoreWorkArguments args)
> CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers (System.Boolean
> throwOnFirstException)
>
> CancellationTokenSource.ExecuteCallbackHandlers (System.Boolean
> throwOnFirstException) CancellationTokenSource.NotifyCancellation
> (System.Boolean throwOnFirstException)
> CancellationTokenSource.TimerCallbackLogic (System.Object obj)
> Timer+Scheduler.TimerCB (System.Object o)
> IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch ()

In my iOS AppDelegate.cs I have AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event handler but it also is not getting hit in the above code.
It would be nice to log the exception rather than crash the app.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @user1034912 I was not able to solve the problem. It still randomly crashes while getting the users location on iOS.

Comment: Sad Indeed... Silly me for not going for flutter... at least their native code is truly native (not intepreted like mono)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` not being called is apparently a [bug](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15252).

There is a workaround mentioned in the bug item which enables the event to be invoked:

```
ObjCRuntime.Runtime.MarshalManagedException += (_, exceptionArgs) =>
{
    exceptionArgs.ExceptionMode = ObjCRuntime.MarshalManagedExceptionMode.UnwindNativeCode;
};
```

YMMV.